# Structuremap default registry dynamic values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap, structuremap4

i am trying to inject a string into structuremap registry at run time. i have successfully done it with a static string. like this

```
For<TestDAL>().Use<TestDAL>().Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is("randomStringData");
```

but when i am trying to make the string dynamic at runtime i am not able to figure out how to send it, i have tried HttpContext and Session but they are always empty like the example below:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment.TryGetValue("dynamicString", out object dynString);  

For<TestDAL>().Use<TestDAL>().Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(dynString);
```

Please anyone has anyidea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're only evaluating the `dynamicString` completely upfront. You might need to do it lazy so it's evaluated just in time like so:

```
For<TestDAL>().Use<TestDAL>().Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(() => {
    string dynString = null;

    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
        .Environment.TryGetValue("dynamicString", out object dynString); 

    return dynString;
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help but this solution is not feasible since lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree. and it wont work

Comment: Use the **other** overload that lets you supply a description as a string and a Func<IContext, T> instead of the expression.

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how to